# Дефис или тире: "другом Игорем - профессором МГУ"

Tags: орфография, синтаксис, пунктуация

Тут нужен дефис или тире?

> Я встретился со своим другом Игорем - профессором МГУ.

Так как вместо дефиса можно поставить "а именно".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно выделить уточнение, а значит, подойдут тире или запятая.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то, это не уточнение, а приложение. По правилу, приложение, носящее пояснительный характер, а особенно такое, какое стоит в конце предложения, выделяется не запятой, а тире. Так что здесь запятая неуместна, так как при постановке запятой может возникнуть двусмысленность: я встретился со своим другом Игорем и еще встретился с профессором МГУ

Comment: Никак не вижу двусмысленности. По-моему, с запятой все довольно однозначно. Было бы это два разных человека - был бы союз "и". Иначе никто не говорит. То есть Ваше предположение чисто теоретическое. Может, поставить запятую - не лучший вариант, но, на мой взгляд, вполне допустимый.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что ставить запятую - не самый лучший вариант: иначе конструкцию "профессором МГУ" можно просто принять за дополнение. Поддерживаю Виктора.

Comment: Согласна с тире. Но с замечанием "это не уточнение, а приложение" - не соглашусь. Нет, это, конечно, приложение. Но противопоставлять их нельзя. Приложение - это вид определения, второстепенного члена предложения. Уточнение- это не член предложения. А приложение вполне может носить уточняющий характер.

Comment: Хочу напомнить уважаемой коллеге, что уточнение - это уточняющий член предложения. Чаще всего уточняющими являются обстоятельства места и времени, реже - определения (цитирую по памяти Розенталя). О приложениях подобного типа он пишет как о членах предложения, носящих не уточнительный, а пояснительный характер.

Comment: Согласен, что запятая не вызвала бы двусмысленности, но поставить надо тире.